# Create select dropdown in react-native with redux-form not sending data

Tags: react-native, select, redux-form

I am completely new in react native, have created signup page, but need to add dropdown, to select locations of user.
Outside of render I have following code

```
  renderPicker = ({
    input: {onChange, value, ...inputProps},
    children,
    ...pickerProps
  }) => (
    <Picker
      selectedValue={value}
      onValueChange={(value) => onChange(value)}
      {...inputProps}
      {...pickerProps}>
      {children}
    </Picker>
  );
```

While in render I am using field with following codes

```
        <Field
          name="newLocations"
          component={this.renderPicker}
          iosHeader="Select one"
          mode="dropdown">
          <Item label="Home" value="Home" />
          <Item label="Office" value="Office" />
          <Item label="Restaurant" value="Restaurant" />
        </Field>
```

It is giving all options, but when I select it, it is not sending data to redux-form. This select box data is not coming. Do I need to create another component of this as for Input I followed tutorial created new component.

Comment: Where does the `Picker` component come from?

Comment: import from 'react-native'

Comment: might be a known issue 
https://github.com/redux-form/redux-form/issues/3243

Comment: Sorry no it does not solve issue, I changed picker to @react-native-community/picker but still no luck.